# MySQL FullText Search not returning any results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am trying to use mysql FULLTEXT search to create a search for my site.

When I run this query, I get results:

```
select * from weapons WHERE MATCH(`model`,`action`,`caliber`) against('ev2 blue *' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

When I run this query, I get none:

```
Select * from weapons WHERE MATCH(`model`,`action`,`caliber`) against('ev2 *' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

So one might assume I don't have enough characters in my search, so I tried this and get results:

```
select * from weapons WHERE MATCH(`model`,`action`,`caliber`) against('100 *' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I am really stuck on how to properly execute this query. All help is appreciated.

Comment: I just checked the ft_min_word_len and it is set to 2. Now I am really lost.

Comment: What happens when you run "select * from weapons WHERE MATCH(`model`,`action`,`caliber`) against('blue *' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"?

Comment: I actually Figured it out, I had to rebuild the index after I set   ft_min_word_len=2.